# Detect if password is expired from ssh

Tags: ssh, rhel, ansible

How to catch expired (own) password from ssh, from non-root account ?
Expect is not installed on target servers.

I need to catch two states with single command:

1. password is expired → when you login, you immediately need to type current password and two new passwords.
2. password is ok → only need to change pwd. It can be done with

   ```
   printf "%s\n" oldpass newpass newpass | passwd
   ```

Something like

```
ssh user@host `if [[ pwd=expired ]]; then printf "%s\n" oldpass newpass newpass; else printf "%s\n" oldpass newpass newpass | passwd; fi`
```

I need to use it with Ansible, it should be simple.

Comment: This bug exists which relates to this:
https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/1619

I suspect there is no easy workaround for that.